# Vandermonde-like identity mixing combination and permutation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations

Do you know any identity that could reduce the following quantity:

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{min(p,n)}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\binom{p}{k}$

It looks like Vandermonde identity where addends are multiplied by $k!$. Any help on either case $p<n$ or $n<p$ is welcome.